# relational algebra to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

Having this schema :

```
Doctor(license_no, doctor_name, specialty)

Patient(pat_id, pat_name, pat_address, pat_phone, date_of_birth)

Visit(license_no, pat_id, date_of_visit, type, diagnosis, charge)
```

I have to translate `Patient (join sign) pat_id(date>=1-1-2005^ date<1-1-2006(Visit))`
and I thought it means to select patients who visited a doctor between 1/1/2005 and 1/1/2006 so I made this query:

```
SELECT p.pat_ID FROM Patient p INNER JOIN Visit v 
ON (p.pat_ID = v.pat_ID)
WHERE date_of_visit <= '01-01-2005' AND date_of_visit < '01-01-2006'
```

Does the relational algebra statement mean what I thought and the SQL query returns the right result?

Comment: Are you noticing the typo in your SQL query?

Comment: yea, if you are talking about the name of column date_of_visit?

Comment: The standard formats for dates are `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD`. So, it's better to write your dates as `2005-01-01` or `20050101`

Comment: Note mySQL has `NATURAL JOIN`, which is closer fit to your algebra statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying a date range for a WHERE condition, you have the right syntax, but your first operator looks incorrect. (`>=` not `<=`).

If you need to select records between two dates including the start date but excluding the end date (known as closed-open representation), the syntax should be as follows:

```
...
WHERE date_of_visit >= date_start AND date_of_visit < date_end
```

If you need to select records between two dates *excluding* those dates, the syntax should be as follows:

```
...
WHERE date_of_visit > date_start AND date_of_visit < date_end
```

If you want to select records between two dates *including* those dates, you should use:

```
...
WHERE date_of_visit >= date_start AND date_of_visit <= date_end
```

The greater-than and equals operators allow you to specify whether you want the date range to be *inclusive* of the boundary dates or not.

Comment: can't i include the start date and exclude the end date?

Comment: Sure: `WHERE date_of_visit >= date_start AND date_of_visit < date_end`

Comment: ah, i understand now what typo you mean :D, thanks, i wish i could vote up your answer but soon i will :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You can select it as the one you used by clicking the check-mark. Thanks.